# nginx: http requests to the new servers are redirected to an old one

Tags: nginx, laravel-forge

I use laravel forge to configure my nginx. It ads new servers(sites) by making a config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enable` directory, which is included in `nginx.conf`. The first site there works well:

#### a.example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name a.example.com;
    root /home/forge/a.example.com/public;
    ...
}
```

However, when I added another site there, namely b.example.com, using the same tools, all the request to b.example.com are delivered to a.example.com instead.

#### b.example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name b.example.com
    root /home/forge/b.example.com/public;
    ...
}
```

Can someone help me out of this mess?

Comment: Have you restarted nginx?

Comment: I did `sudo service nginx restart`. But I think the process id of nginx remains the same. Is that OK?

Comment: Nope. Try to stop nginx completely and then start

Comment: service nginx stop does not work. Why?

Comment: There are plenty of reasons. May be it wasn't srarted by service at all. May service lost nginx's pid somehow. You should investigate it.

Comment: I did /etc/init.d/nginx restart. Sounds like it worked.